# Build a sentence from tokens / words in a String-Array java

Tags: java, string, sentence

How do I joint the words in `list<String>` in order to back to it's real form as sentences

```
String sentence = "i get money. i love it. i want to buy. something. ";
String[] arrSent = sentence.split("\\. ");

for(int i=0; i<arrSent.length; i++) {
    String[] words = arrSent[i].split("\\ ");
    for(int j=0; j<words.length; j++ {
        listWord.add(words[j]);
    }
}
```

and the output is :

```
i
get
money
i
love
it
i
want
to
buy
something
```

i just trying to rebuild it to the real form (as sentence)

update!!!

i have tried like you suggest guys. but i found a new difficult way.

i have removed one word "love" from list and i add to new list "listWord2" . when i rebuild it to real form as sentence, the `.` in new sentence is disappear

this is the code :

```
String [] arrays2 = listKata2.toArray(new String[listWord2.size()]);
sentence = Arrays.deepToString(arrays2).replaceAll(",", "");
System.out.println("result :  : "+sentence);
```

and the ouput is :

```
[i get money i it i want to buy something]
```

the `.` is missing

should i split the `listWord2` by space again ?, please suggest me

Comment: Declare a string, loop the array and add every item to that string. BTW if you don't store somewhere the original positions of the dots, you'll not be able to fully rebuild it

Comment: Print each element and ad `. ` after it.

Comment: I believe you missed a closing parentheses `)` on the second `for-loop`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real answer is that once you take all the words and lose the full stops between the sentences, there is no way to bring them back - that information is lost forever and it is then impossible to reconstruct the original structure.

You need to figure out how (and really, *if*) you want to retain that information. One way is you keep your sentence array, just populate it with word lists instead of sentence strings, something like this:

```
List<List<String>> sentences = new List<List<String>>();
String[] arrSent = sentence.split("\\. ");
for (int i = 0; i < arrSent.length; i++)
    sentences.add(Arrays.asList(arrSend[i].split("\\ "));
```

Then you'd get something like

```
(
   ( "i", "get", "money" ),
   ( "i", "love", "it" ),
   ( "i", "want", "to", "buy" ),
   ( "something" )
)
```

which is easy to see how to reconstruct the original text from this.

Another option might be to keep the flattened list of words, but add special place holders for where the sentence termination used to be - for example using `null` values. An algorithm scanning the words should know how to deal with these place holders without crashing, while the algorithm to reconstruct the sentence would use those to add the full stops:

```
String[] arrSent = sentence.split("\\. ");

for(int i=0; i<arrSent.length; i++) {
    String[] words = arrSent[i].split("\\ ");
    for(int j=0; j<words.length; j++ {
        listWord.add(words[j]);
    }
    listWord.add(null);
}

// Rebuild
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
for (Iterator<String> it = listWord.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
     String val = it.next();
     String nextword = (output.length() > 0 ? " " : "") + val;
     output.append(val == null ? "." : nextword);
}
```

Comment: is there list in list?

Comment: That's a distinct possibility :-)

Comment: the result of your way is not like the real sentence :
the output of yours is : [i get money . i love it . i want to buy . something . ]

there is space between "." and the last word of sentence = "money . "

when the sentence is rebuild it's too difficult to split sentence by sentences because the "." and the last word in sentence has space

can you fix it, brother?

Comment: Yes, it's because the code adds a space after each word. It should be trivial to fix by changing the code to add the space *before* the word, but only if the string buffer is not empty. Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: can you describe it, please.. i can't implements your code like you suggest. please

Answer (score -1):

Try Following:

```
String sentence = "i get money. i love it. i want to buy. something. ";
String[] arrSent = sentence.split(" ");
sentence=Arrays.toString(arrSent).replaceAll(",", "");
System.out.println(sentence);
```

**Output :**

```
[i get money. i love it. i want to buy. something.]
```

Above is if you want `.` in the sentence, below is without `.`.

```
String sentence = "i get money. i love it. i want to buy. something. ";
String[] arrSent = sentence.split("\\. ");
sentence=Arrays.toString(arrSent).replaceAll(",", "");
System.out.println(sentence);
```

**Output :**

```
[i get money i love it i want to buy something]
```

Comment: your `arrSent ` will contain `.` too

Comment: Yes because it is there in the original string.

Comment: but they dont want `.` in the `arrSent ` check that

Comment: in the `arrSent ` there should not be `.` but the `rebuild sentence` should be same as `sentence`

Comment: I don't like this abuse of a specific implementation's `toString()` implementation. Besides the obvious, the `toString()` implementations aren't speced and are likely to differ between implementations or change without notice.

Comment: i have removed one word "love" from list. and i want to rebuild it to real form without word "love" .

i have tried but i miss "." in my new sentence

Answer (score -1):

Do:

```
String sentence = "i get money. i love it. i want to buy. something. ";
String[] arrSent = sentence.split("\\. ");

String sentenceRebuild = "";
for(int i=0; i<arrSent.length; i++){
  String[] words = arrSent[i].split("\\ ");

  for(int j=0; j<words.length; j++){
    sentenceRebuild += words[j];
  }
}
```

Comment: your are missing `)` for 2nd `for` loop